# I want to add a 'fixed navigation bar' and 'back to top' button in my website with same javascript file

Tags: javascript, css

Here is my HTML file, it contains button and navigation bar code which points at same javascript file called scrollOn.js.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stickOn.css">
</head> 
<body>
    <div class="header" id="homeScroll">
        <h1>Company Name and logo</h1>
        <p>Tagline of company</p>
    </div>
    <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>
    <div id="navbar">
            <a href="#"><img alt="logo_small" src="images/home.png" style="width:19px;height:16px;"></a>
            <a href="#homeScroll">Home</a>
            <a href="#serviceScroll">Services</a>
            <a href="#companyScroll">Company</a>
            <a href="#aboutScroll" class="right">About Us</a>
    </div>
    <script src="js/scrollOn.js"></script> <!-- Always write SCRIPT declaration at the END of BODY -->
    <script src="js/slideImg.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/back2top.js"></script>-->
</body>
```

Here is my CSS file which may not be as usable in scenario but is contains basic structure and positions for my navigation bar and back to top button

```
@charset "ISO-8859-1";
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 font-family: century gothic;
}
#navbar {
 z-index: 500;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #333;
}
#navbar a {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar a.right {
 float: right;
}
#navbar a:hover {
 background-color: #ddd;
 color: black;
}
#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #ff8080;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.sticky {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 98.8%;
}
.category {
 padding: 10px;
 background: #000000;
 text-align: center;
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

and here is JAVA SCRIPT file in which myFunction() doesn't seem to execute two sentences at a time.

```
window.onscroll = function() {
 myFunction()
};
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
function myFunction() {
 if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
 } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
 }
}
function topFunction() {
 document.body.scrollTop = 0;
 document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

In the above java script file 'myFunction()' doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please create a working example and remove unwanted code. Happy to help you.

Comment: Did you wrap onscorll inside a listener?